# Posting to a PHP script with Ajax (Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

I have an application that I'm writing that, in one aspect of it, you click on a checkmark to complete a task, a popup window is displayed (using bootstrap), you enter your hours, and then that is sent to a PHP page to update the database. I'm using FF (firebug) to view the post. It's coming up red but not giving me an error. The only thing I'm doing is echoing out "sup" on the PHP page, and it's still showing errors, and I can't figure out why.

This is my initial click function:

```
$('.complete').on('click', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var span = $(tr).children('td.task-name');

    var r = (confirm('Are you sure you want to complete this task?'));

    if (r){
        addHours(id);
    } else {
        return false;
    } // end else
});
```

That works fine, and it fires my next function which actually fires the bootstrap modal:

```
function addHours(id) {

    var url = 'load/hours.php?id='+id;

    $.get(url, function(data) {

        $('<div class="modal hide fade in" id="completeTask">' + data + '</div>').modal()
        .on('shown', function() {

            pendingTask(id);

        }); // end callback 

        }).success(function() { 

        $('input:text:visible:first').focus(); 
    });

} // end function
```

This is also working, and the modal is displayed just fine. However, whenever I post the form to my logic page, it fails for no reason. This is the function to post the form to the logic page:

```
function pendingTask(id) {

$('.addHours').on('click', function(event) {

        var formData = $('form#CompleteTask').serializeObject();
            $.ajax({
                  url:'logic/complete-with-hours.php',
                  type: 'POST', 
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: formData,
                  success: function(data) {
                      if (data.status == 'error') {     
                          $(this).attr('checked', false);
                          //location.reload();
                      } // end if       
                      else  { 
                          $(this).attr('checked', true);
                          //location.reload();
                      } // end else      
                  },
                dataType: 'json'
            });     

}); // end click

} // end function
```

When this is fired, I see this in my Firebug console:
[image: There is no error code from the console, and remember the only thing on that page is echo "sup"; so it's not like I'm trying to execute PHP code that is erroring out.]

I know this is a lot of information, but I wanted to provide as much information as I could. Every other post function in the application is working fine. It's just this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I changed the post type from the structure I entered above to a standard post:

```
$("#CompleteTask").validate({

                submitHandler: function(form) {

                    var hours = $('#hours').val();

                        $.post('logic/complete-with-hours.php', {'hours': hours, 'id':id}, 

                            function(data){ 

                                if (data.status == 'success') { 
                                    $(checkmark).attr('checked', false);
                                    $('.message').html(data.message).addClass('success').show();                                        
                                } // end if 

                                if (data.status == 'error') { 
                                    $('.message').html(data.message).addClass('error').show();  
                                } // end else                                           
                            },
                        "json"
                        ); //end POST                                                   
                } // end submit handler 
            }); // end validate
```

That seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The `jQuery.ajax` `data` parameter takes a simple object of key value pairs. The problem could be that the object created by `serializeObject()` is too complex. If that's the case, you could either process the `formData` object to simplify it or try `data: JSON.stringify(formData)`

Comment: I've tried adding in JSON.stringify(formData) to the data attribute but it's not working for me. Also I was having this issue before I tried to serialize the form.

Before, I was using this:

var id = $('#id').val();
var hours = $('#hours').val();

and then my data object would be:

data: {'id':id', 'hours':hours}

Answer (score 0):

Does serializeObject() even exist in jQuery? is that a function you wrote yourself? Can you use jQuery functions like serialize() or serializeArray() to serialize the form data and see how it goes.

Comment: its a jquery plugin that I've used for a while. Saves time on setting all the form values to variables. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: you are pointing me towards serialize while you are using serializeObject. I know there is a plugin called serializeObject but i was wondering if the plugin has some problem which might be causing problems for you. Have you tried using serializeArray or serialize from jQuery itself to see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the red indicates a `404` response error.  We can't tell in this screen shot.  Check your php code by directly calling the requested page and getting a proper response.

Also make sure your `dataType` is `application/json`  which is the proper mime type header (though I don't think this is causing the error). You also should only have `dataType` once (you have it again at the bottom)